# Disabling caching in my MVC project except for specific actions's controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I work on my Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET MVC4 solution. I am busy on the caching part. I would like to have no actions controller cached except some specific actions marked by an attribute.

Here is what I do:

I defined an action filter:

```
public class DisableCacheFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Without caching
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    }
}
```

So whenever an action is triggered, I don't cache for the next time this action is triggered.

Next I register this filter in Global.asax:

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new DisableCacheFilter());
    }
```

Next I created an EnableCache attribute:

```
public class EnableCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // With caching of one day
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    }
}
```

So whenever the current action is decorated with EnableCache attribute, I would like to cache it. So next time the same action is triggered (from the client browser), no call is made.

Example:

```
    [EnableCache]
    public JsonResult GetPostCode(int countryID, string term)
    {
    ....
    }
```

It doesn't work because each time the filter DisableCache is called.

So in resume: I would like to disable any cache (from browser) and only cache specific actions (maybe marked by an attribute).

Is it possible?

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you considered [output caching](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs)? The linked example is for an older version of MVC, but the concept is the same, just use the [OutputCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.108).aspx) attribute.

Comment: I would like by default NO CACHE on actions and enabling only cache for specific actions. I don't want to set an OutputCache attribute on every action to enable/disable cache on it. Do you see what I try to achieve?

Comment: I think so, but by default there should be no caching, so it'd only be a case of adding OutputCache attributes to just the actions you want to cache the output for. Actions that don't need caching, you can just leave without any cache-related attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the attribute to your GlobalFilterCollection

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new DisableCacheFilter());
        filters.Add(new EnableCacheAttribute ());
    }
```